# How to add Queue Description at Rabbitmq Admin UI using Pika library?

Tags: rabbitmq, pika

We are using pika library to declare exchange and queues as mentioned in the example below,

```py
queue_declare(queue='process_messages_dx', durable=True)
```

Now, How to add Queue Description such that Admin UI user(Administrator, DevOps team) gets the knowledge of what this queue's function is. Kind of metadata of the Queue.

Reference: https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/adapters/blocking.html?highlight=queue_declare#pika.adapters.blocking_connection.BlockingChannel.queue_declare

[image]

Comment: @medium-dimensional I have noticed many times in the past where documentation links gets updated and question losts it's context. btw, link is also attached.

Comment: Oh, yes, that makes sense! I didn't realise it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible by just adding arguments as mentioned in the Pika Documentation,

```py
metadata = {
  "about": "Contains notification messages sent from the system. Consumed by the Flash to deliver content to Justice League.",
  "service": "earth"
}

queue_declare(queue='process_messages_dx', durable=True, arguments=metadata)
```